# Are there alternate axiomatisations for ZFC set theory?

Tags: soft-question, set-theory, axioms

To be clear, I am not looking for alternate versions of set theory which may be strictly stronger or weaker, or incomparable to ZFC.

What I am curious about is whether there are any interesting sets of axioms which are exactly equivalent to ZFC logically speaking, but significantly different in presentation or character. I think it is often beneficial for something as foundational as ZFC to gain multiple perspectives and interpretations.

Comment: IIRC, bounded Zermelo set theory is equivalent to the theory of a well-pointed topos with natural number object, which in turn is equivalent to a kind of dependent type theory. IIRC choice is easy to add in. I don't know what the state of the art is for the unbounded version, or if you want to include the F parts.

Comment: Search for Quine's *New Foundation*.

Comment: @Berci, OP asks for logically equivalent theories to ZFC, which NF is not.

Comment: @Hurkyl: If my memory serves me right, you just need to add a schema for Replacement. Which can be done, apparently.

Comment: These aren't significant differences, but it's still worth mentioning that there are individual axioms we can tweak in various simple ways. There are of course many known variants of the axiom of choice - that is, principles which are equivalent, over ZF, to AC as usually stated. Foundation has a couple alternate phrasings. One is the principle of **set induction**: this is the scheme which asserts, for each formula $\varphi$, that $$\forall x(\forall y\in x(\varphi(y))\implies\varphi(x))\implies\forall z(\varphi(z)).$$ (Actually, as usual I want the "parameterized" version of this, but meh.)

Comment: Another is the **cumulative hierarchy principle**, that every set is a member of $V_\alpha$ for some ordinal $\alpha$. Replacement/Collection can be rephrased as [a transfinite recursion principle](http://jdh.hamkins.org/transfinite-recursion-as-a-fundamental-principle-in-set-theory/). Finally, from Separation and Replacement we can produce a wide variety of principles equivalent (over ZF-Inf) to Infinity - e.g. that $V_\omega$ exists, or that there is a Dedekind-infinite set, or etc.

Comment: You can axiomatize things using "function" and "composition" as primitives, rather than "set" and "membership".  Maybe look in http://www.iep.utm.edu/lambda-calculi/

Comment: @GEdgar does this produce a system strictly equivalent to ZFC? Because that was what my question was about, not just an alternate system of maths.